# sidekiq two methods on delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

How I can do something like that at sidekiq?

```
Gateway::AddUser.delay.new(6).call
```

For now, `Gateway::AddUser.delay.new(6)` return a string, and `call` method trying to run on it. But I want to call just `Gateway::AddUser.new(6).call` delayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved just like this:

```
Gateway::AddUser.delay.perform(6)
```

Where `perform` method is:

```
def self.perform(params)
  new(params).call
end
```

Just rewrite 2 methods to 1 =)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just wrap that in other method?

```
class User
  def self.add_user_via_gateway(attributes)
    Gateway::AddUser.new(attributes).call
  end
end

User.delay.add_user_via_gatway(attributes)
```

EDIT:

If you prefer, you can also create a worker class.

```
class AddUserViaGatewayWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(attributes)
    Gateway::AddUser.new(attributes).call
  end
end

AddUserViaGatewayWorker.perform_async(attributes)
```

Comment: I can walk this way, but it seems a bit complex: I'll make my model fat

Comment: Why is this making your moodel fat? Anyway, you can put the code inside any other module or class that you prefer. Or you can create a worker class.

Comment: Model is not responsing for delayed actions, right? Worker class seems perfect solution.

Comment: In the first solution, the model is not aware if the method will be executed in background or not. Since it's a create action, I think it fits well inside the model, but that depends on how the application is organized.